# data not getting fetched from database using hibernate in correct format

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i want to fetch a list of  student data from database using hibernate HQL but after running the code data is not getting fetched in correct form and instead returning something else and there are no errors.
Here is the attached code and output

[program image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtiiZ.jpg)

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk3H6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

`Student` has not overridden `toString()` method therefore you see the Java default `toString()` method that prints the class name and the reference.

You must implement `toString()` on the `Student` class to see anything else.

Comment: Hi Suyash. If it's solves your problem consider accepting the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers